# PaperDbException

Tags: android, paperdb

Library link : https://github.com/pilgr/Paper

This crash is occurred in some devices.

```
Fatal Exception: io.paperdb.PaperDbException: Couldn't read/deserialize file /data/data/com.cittacode.trocandofraldas/files/io.paperdb/week_pages.pt for table week_pages
   at io.paperdb.DbStoragePlainFile.readTableFile(DbStoragePlainFile.java:298)
   at io.paperdb.DbStoragePlainFile.select(DbStoragePlainFile.java:158)
   at io.paperdb.Book.read(Book.java:73)
   at io.paperdb.Book.read(Book.java:58)...
```

Another crash log:

Caused by com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
Serialization trace:

```
mContent (io.paperdb.PaperTable)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:199)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readVarInt(Input.java:373)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:127)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:693)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:804)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:153)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:734)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:543)
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:712)
   at io.paperdb.DbStoragePlainFile.readContent(DbStoragePlainFile.java:307)
   at io.paperdb.DbStoragePlainFile.readTableFile(DbStoragePlainFile.java:291)
   at io.paperdb.DbStoragePlainFile.select(DbStoragePlainFile.java:158)
   at io.paperdb.Book.read(Book.java:73)
   at io.paperdb.Book.read(Book.java:58)...
```

It seems that issue is in library. I am using 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'

Comment: are you using proguard ?

Comment: @Lucifer No, I am not using proguard.

Comment: @Lucifer I've the same issue, that occurs sporadically. And I use pro guard. So what  was your thought on that?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: this occurs due to proguard rules

Comment: Fixed my issue by upgrading to latest Paper version 2.7.2. It was happenign due to proguard rules.

Answer (score 1):

Just make minifyenabled false, shrinkResources false

Comment: Refrence: https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , In my case I was trying to read a Serializable class from Paper .
like

```
 ProfileClass profileClass = Paper.book().read(profile);
```

and the class  implemented  Serializable

```
public class ProfileData implements Serializable
```

I just removed the `Serializable` and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I encountered to the same stacktrace when debugging 'on boot' listener (android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED action) on 'Nexus One (Google API) 29' emulator.

Paper DB version: 'io.github.pilgr:paperdb:2.7.2' (by now is the last one)

This is [known issue](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper/issues/4). The following comment with workaround from [here](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper/issues/119) helped me:

> The second read attempt should fix the problem (as app restart after
> crash solves it now). Could be added as a workaround to the lib. But I
> don't see it's as a major issue now. Closing this one as a duplicate
> of [#4](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper/issues/4)

Fix that helped to me is the following:

```
int log_count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    try {
        log_count = Paper.book("system_config").read("log_count", 0);
    }
    catch (io.paperdb.PaperDbException e) {
        String msg = String.format("Try num: %s, PaperDbException: %s", i, e.getMessage());
        write_log_file(context, msg, new_file_mode);
    }
}
```